# IOError: 13 Permission Denied

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, arff

Sorry for the annoying question, I know that there are several topics on similar problems but I couldn't find the solution in any of them. I am trying to run my code and I receive an error "Permission denied". Some say it is a Windows problem rather than a Python one but still I cannot managed to find the solution. Can you please help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
#/usr/share/bin/python2

import re, os, sys
error_to_catch = getattr(__builtins__,'FileNotFoundError', IOError)

def splitFiles(inputPos, inputNeg, directory):
        print directory
        dirPos = directory + "/positive"
        dirNeg = directory + "/negative"
        os.mkdir(dirPos)
        os.mkdir(dirNeg)

        for i in range(len(inputPos)):
            outputNeg = open(os.path.join(dirNeg, str(i+1) + ".txt"), "w")
            outputPos = open(os.path.join(dirPos, str(i+1) + ".txt"), "w")

            outputNeg.write(inputNeg[i])
            outputPos.write(inputPos[i])

            outputNeg.close()
            outputPos.close()



def getUnigrams(sentence):
    x = sentence.replace("'", "")
    y = x.replace("--", "")
    z = y.replace("_", " ")

    wordList = re.findall("[\w']+", z)

    return wordList


def arffOutput(inputPos, inputNeg, directory):
    print directory
    """ Creates an ARFF file from the given set of sentences.
    First, split each sentences into unigrams, remove apostrophies as it's
    not supported by the ARFF standard.
    Then, create a joint list of tokens that are both in positive and
    negative sets, and remove them from each sets.
    We are thus left with lists that have tokens only in positive, only
    in negative, or both.
    At last, create the structure of the arff file and put each token in.

    @param sentences: a list of strings.

    """
    output = open(directory + "_tokens.arff", "w")
    output.write("@RELATION sentiments\n")



    wordListPos = []
    wordListNeg = []
    unigrams = []

    for sentence in inputPos:
        wordList = getUnigrams(sentence)
        for word in wordList:
            wordListPos.append(word)
            unigrams.append(word)

    for sentence in inputNeg:
        wordList = getUnigrams(sentence)
        for word in wordList:
            wordListNeg.append(word)
            unigrams.append(word)

    wordListPos = list(set(wordListPos))
    wordListNeg = list(set(wordListNeg))
    unigrams = list(set(unigrams))

    for word in unigrams:
        output.write("@ATTRIBUTE " + str(word) + " {yes,no}\n")

    output.write("@ATTRIBUTE CLASS {positive,negative}\n@data\n")

    for sentence in inputPos:
        outputString = ""
        wordsInSentence = getUnigrams(sentence)
        for word in unigrams:
            if word in wordsInSentence:
                outputString += "yes,"
            else:
                outputString += "no,"

        outputString += "positive\n"
        output.write(outputString)

    for sentence in inputNeg:
        outputString = ""
        wordsInSentence = getUnigrams(sentence)
        for word in unigrams:
            if word in wordsInSentence:
                outputString += "yes,"
            else:
                outputString += "no,"

        outputString += "negative\n"
        output.write(outputString)


    output.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = sys.argv

    if(len(argv) > 1):
        for i in range(1, len(argv)):
            fileInput = open(argv[i], "r")
            f = fileInput.read()
            fileInput.close()
            f = f.replace("_", " ")
            f = f.replace("--", " ") #in original/MR-neg.txt
            charCount = len(set(f))
            wordList = re.findall("[\w']+", f)
            wordCount = len(wordList)
            uniqueWordCount = len(set(wordList))
            print "chars\twords\tunique word"
            print charCount , "\t" , wordCount , "\t" , uniqueWordCount,
            "\t", argv[i]
    else:
        directories = ["original","remove_stop_word",
        "stemming_and_remove_stop_word"]

        for directory in directories:
            filePos =open('C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/DataMining_B/Data/data', 'r')
            fileNeg =open('C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/DataMining_B/Data/data', 'r')

            sentencesPos = filePos.readlines()
            sentencesNeg = fileNeg.readlines()

            filePos.close()
            fileNeg.close()

            splitFiles(sentencesPos, sentencesNeg, directory)
            arffOutput(sentencesPos, sentencesNeg, directory)
```

*for directory in directories:
            filePos =open('C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/DataMining_B/Data/data', 'r')
            fileNeg =open('C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/DataMining_B/Data/data', 'r')*

The error line is empahasized

Comment: Are you sure your file is `'C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/DataMining_B/Data/data'`. It looks like this is the path and you're missing the file name.

Comment: One of the most common causes of that error on windows is trying to open a directory rather than a file. I think that's what's happening here?

Comment: I tried all possible ways. I tried setting a path directly to the file itself, then I tried with the directory and still it didn't work.